# How to submit a kubectl job and pass the user as runas

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have a container that I want to run on Kubernetes Let's say image1

when I run kubectl apply -f somePod.yml (which runs the image1) how can I start the image with the user that runned the command kubectl?

Comment: Could you elaborate? You want to run container which will be able to execute `kubectl` (You can create  your own image with kubectl using Dockerfile). Then you want to execute commands inside this container as person who run the job? Or you just want to pass username as variable to container? Are you using Baremetal or On-Prem?

Comment: What's a "user"?  (Each container in each pod will have its own `/etc/passwd` file and could run on a different node with different host passwd files; it's also unusual for pods to share files in a way where this would matter.)

Comment: A user is a person with kubectl installed on their laptops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible [by design](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/service-accounts-admin/#user-accounts-vs-service-accounts). Please find explanation below:

In the most cases Jobs create Pods, so I use Pods in my explanation.
In case of Jobs it means just a bit different YAML file.

```
$ kubectl explain job.spec.
$ kubectl explain job.spec.template.spec
```

**Users** run `kubectl` using [**user accounts**.](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/)

**Pods** are runing using [**service accounts**](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/). There is no way to run pod `"from user account"`.
**Note:** in recent versions `spec.ServiceAccount` was replaced by `spec.serviceAccountName`

*However*, you can use **user account credentials** by running `kubectl` inside a Pod's container or making `curl` requests to Kubernetes `api-server` from inside a pod container.
Using [Secrets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) is the most convenient way to do that.

What else you can do differentiate users in the cluster:

- create a [namespace](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces/) for each user
- [limit user permission to specific namespace](https://jeremievallee.com/2018/05/28/kubernetes-rbac-namespace-user.html)
- create default service account in that namespace.

This way if the user creates a Pod without specifying `spec.ServiceAccountName`, by default it will use `default` service-account from Pod's namespace.

You can even set for the `default service account` the same permissions as for the `user account`. The only difference would be that `service accounts` exist in the *specific namespace*.

If you need to use the same namespace for all users, you can use [helm charts](https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/) to set the correct `serviceAccountName` for each user *( imagine you have service-accounts with the same name as users )* by using [--set](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/using_helm/#customizing-the-chart-before-installing) command line arguments as follows:

```
$ cat testchart/templates/job.yaml 
...
   serviceAccountName: {{ .Values.saname }}
...

$ export SANAME=$(kubectl config view --minify -o jsonpath='{.users[0].name}')
$ helm template ./testchart --set saname=$SANAME
---
# Source: testchart/templates/job.yaml
...
   serviceAccountName: kubernetes-admin
...
```

You can also specify `namespace` for each user in the same way.

Comment: Marking this as the correct response at it is not possible and this anwser is for me the best explained

Answer (score 0):

I am still not sure if I good understood your question.

However, `kubectl` doesn't have an option to pass user or service account when creating jobs:

`kubectl create job --help`

```
Create a job with the specified name.

Examples:
  # Create a job
  kubectl create job my-job --image=busybox

  # Create a job with command
  kubectl create job my-job --image=busybox -- date

  # Create a job from a CronJob named "a-cronjob"
  kubectl create job test-job --from=cronjob/a-cronjob

Options:
      --allow-missing-template-keys=true: If true, ignore any errors in templates when a field or
map key is missing in the template. Only applies to golang and jsonpath output formats.
      --dry-run=false: If true, only print the object that would be sent, without sending it.
      --from='': The name of the resource to create a Job from (only cronjob is supported).
      --image='': Image name to run.
  -o, --output='': Output format. One of:
json|yaml|name|go-template|go-template-file|template|templatefile|jsonpath|jsonpath-file.
      --save-config=false: If true, the configuration of current object will be saved in its
annotation. Otherwise, the annotation will be unchanged. This flag is useful when you want to
perform kubectl apply on this object in the future.
      --template='': Template string or path to template file to use when -o=go-template,
-o=go-template-file. The template format is golang templates
[http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#pkg-overview].
      --validate=true: If true, use a schema to validate the input before sending it

Usage:
  kubectl create job NAME --image=image [--from=cronjob/name] -- [COMMAND] [args...] [flags]
[options]

Use "kubectl options" for a list of global command-line options (applies to all commands).
```

You can specify many factors inside your YAML definition. For example you could create `ServiceAccount` or specify `runAsUser` in a `pod` configuration. However, this requires to have a definition file instead of run-level with `kubectl`.

[Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/#set-the-security-context-for-a-pod) you can find how to do it with `runAsUser` parameter.

You could also consider using [ServiceAccount](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/). [Here](https://medium.com/better-programming/k8s-tips-using-a-serviceaccount-801c433d0023) you have article which might help you. However you would need to create specific `ServiceAccount`
It would look similar like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
   name: pod-demo-sa
spec:
   serviceAccountName: demo-sa
   containers:
   — name: alpine
     image: alpine:3.9
     command:
     — "sleep"
     — "10000"
```

If this would be for some labs or practice you could also think about creating customized docker image using [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/).

Unfortunately previous options are `hardcoded`. Other solution would need a specific scritp and many pipelines.

In addition, as you mentioned in title, to pass some values to configuration you can use [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, the idea would be really that each container runs under  the user that submits the kubectl command. Kind of the same thing as what hadoop has for impersonalisation. (doAs())

Comment: Unfortunately, Kubernetes don't have built-in that kind of functionality. 
It would be possible but you need to chage `serviceAccountName` (probably using some script using deploying).